# Is there diagram for dynamoDB schema like ER diagram for RDBMS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'd like to write documentations of my dynamodb schema.

Is there some diagram for document or should I use ER diagram?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's a good practice to define an ER diagram.  You will establish the entities and their relationship to one another in a DB agnostic way.

While you are at it, I'd suggest creating a document that lists:

- Access Patterns - For example, fetch users by email, fetch orders by status, etc.
- Describe your primary key structure - What are you Primary Key(PK) and Sort Key(SK) patterns?  For example PK ORDER# defines the Order entity, USER#<email_address> defines the USER entity, etc.
- Describe any secondary indexes (PK/SK patterns)

Check out how [Alex DeBrie models his examples](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIQVJqiSUkE) in his AWS talk for a good example.

ER diagrams are a fantastic reference to understand the data model, and I think every database should have one as a part of it's documentation.  With DynamoDB, understanding the access patterns and how the Primary Keys are designed to support the access patterns is critical information.

Answer (score 4):

I love Alex's [book](https://www.dynamodbbook.com/).

I use PlantUML in my documentation generation, which is available online via [Planttext](https://www.planttext.com/). The big benefit for me is that you do the diagram in plain text so it diffs wonderfully, checked in alongside source.

PlantUML has a [standard ERD syntax](https://plantuml.com/ie-diagram) which is an extension of their OO class diagrams. I've abused it slightly in the example below to include some subclassing relationships.

[image: Content store to back a mobile app]

```
@startuml

title Touchgram Content Store

entity Artist {
* Name
* Bio
UsualLicense
}


entity PhysicalGallery {
* Name
* Address
* Contact
Description
}

entity OnlineGallery {
* Name
* WebAddress
Description
}


entity PhysicalProduct {
* Name
Description
}

entity DigitalSale {
* Price
* Timestamp
}
note bottom of DigitalSale : All digital sales\nare totally anonymous\nvia online credit

entity DigitalProduct {
* Name
* DownloadFile
* Price
License
}

entity DigitalAvail {
* Price
* DateRange
Comments
}

Artist }o..|| DigitalProduct
DigitalProduct }o..|| DigitalSale
DigitalProduct }o..|| DigitalAvail
DigitalProduct }o..|{ PhysicalProduct
DigitalProduct <|-- Image
DigitalProduct <|-- Sound
DigitalProduct <|-- VisualEffect
DigitalProduct <|-- Template

Template }o..o{ DigitalProduct : "Uses Other\nProduct"
note bottom of Template : Template Touchgrams\n(eg: greeting cards or memes)\nCan use digital products\nfrom many artists\nso license & sales would\ncascade through

note bottom of DigitalAvail : By default, available\nas soon as in store\nbut restrictions can be added
Artist }o..o{ PhysicalGallery : Exhibits at
Artist }o..o{ OnlineGallery : Advertises
OnlineGallery }o..o{ PhysicalGallery : Advertises
PhysicalProduct }o..o{ OnlineGallery : Sold through
PhysicalProduct }o..o{ PhysicalGallery : Shown at

note "Normally one digital version\nwould exist of a canvas\nbut often offer prints\n\nconversely, more rarely\nmight do several digital\nversions of a work\neg: with different filters\nor even crop portions\n\nWe **do not** handle\nphysical sales" as N1
N1 .. PhysicalProduct
@enduml
```

Comment: Hi Andy, is that all manual process to create the ERD in PlantUML or are there ways to generate it by some scripts in dynamodb ?

Comment: @bschandramohan that was all manual but it is very fast copy and paste in a text editor.